# Which articles are correct in "He is both ___ singer and ___ dancer" ?

Tags: articles, coordination

What will be the articles in the gaps?

> He is both __ singer and __ dancer.

MY ASSUMPTION: a, ×.

I chose to write × for the second gap because, it indicates the same person.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### [The noun phrase](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/nounphrase.htm)

> You can find the noun dog in a sentence, for example, but you don't
>   know which canine the writer means until you consider the entire noun
>   phrase: that dog, Aunt Audrey's dog, the dog on the sofa, the
>   neighbor's dog that chases our cat, the dog digging in the new flower
>   bed. Modifiers can come before or after the noun. Ones that come
>   before might include **articles**, possessive nouns, possessive
>   pronouns, adjectives, and/or participles.

"We" is the subject pronoun and "singer" is the noun, the articles in this noun phrase should be used to assign the nouns to the subject pronoun, the use of the adjective "both" implies they should be grouped and so I would use "a singer and dancer":

- He is both a singer and a dancer.  - Grammatically correct, separates singer and dancer.  This structure would be more suited to "he is <s>both</s> an artist and a scientist", two disparate nouns.
- He is both a singer and dancer. - "He" is the subject pronoun.  The use of the word "both", means that both simultaneously apply.  Therefore "singer and dancer" is an appropriate grouping and better in this context.

Comment: I'd say that 'He is both a singer and a dancer' and 'He is a singer and dancer' both sound a lot more natural than 'He is both a singer and dancer'.

Answer (score 2):

When we use **both..and**, we are using [parallelling](https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/general_writing/mechanics/parallel_structure.html) to attach the first part "He is.." to the both-clause and the and-clause.

If you wanted to talk about a particular person's skills, then an indefinite article or zero article are OK. Zero article makes the sentence sound quite literary: here is a typical example:

> That Jackson was both singer and dancer was evident during the Hollywood Palace broadcast. [Performance and Popular Music: History, Place and Time](https://books.google.co.id/books?id=U92hAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA124&dq=%22both%20singer%20and%20dancer%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjDqr3R9vzYAhVJro8KHWEyC6gQ6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q=%22both%20singer%20and%20dancer%22&f=false)

Using an indefinite article is more straightforward: it is [less common in writing](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a%20singer%20and%20a%20dancer%2C%20singer%20and%20dancer&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20singer%20and%20a%20dancer%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csinger%20and%20dancer%3B%2Cc0) but may be more common in spoken English.

> He is both a singer and a dancer.

If this person is the **only** member of a cast for a show that can sing and dance, you could also say

> He is both the singer and the dancer

Comment: The link leads only to the Purdue Home Page. // 'Whatever you do, it is important that these two clauses are the same' needs a supporting reference. And it is easy to construct counter-examples: 'He is both the Lord of Elbonia and a thoroughly good chap'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth thanks for the feedback. LInk updated and contentious comment removed.

Comment: I've just realised that, for example, ''He is both Lord of Elbonia and master carpenter' uses the null and zero articles (_the_ Lord but _a_ master carpenter) in a conjunctive construction. English can be bewildering.